# Making a delete function for a binary search tree in C++

Tags: c++, performance, recursion, binary-search-tree

Edited*: I'm working on the delete function for a binary search tree. I'm just working on the first case right now. I think this is correct, but I'm wondering if it can be done recursively, or more efficiently. Any help is appreciated. Assume BSTSearch searches for a node, `isLeaf` returns true if the node is a leaf, and each node has a pointer that allows them access to their parent.

```
void
BinarySearchTree::BSTDelete(int x, BSTNode *node){

    BSTNode *deleteNode;
    deleteNode = BSTSearch(x,node); 

    if(isLeaf(deleteNode)){

        if(deleteNode->sortkey > (deleteNode->parent)->sortkey){
             delete (deleteNode->parent)->right;
            (deleteNode->parent)->right = NULL;
        }

        else{
            delete (deleteNode->parent)->left;
            (deleteNode->parent)->left = NULL;  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Deleting from a tree can be a difficult operation. Consider you'll need to know the parent of the node you're deleting, so you can update the child pointer that currently points at your node of interest. Then consider where you are going to put the (possibly more than one) children of the current node, without violating any ordering constraints that you may have (which a BST definitely has). In certain cases you may need to rebalance things all the way up to the root of the tree...

Comment: "Efficiently" is a relative term, and various binary search trees have been researched, each with their own set of pros and cons. See AVL, Red-black, Splay, Treap, Tango, etc. trees...

Comment: This doesn't look correct. You are deleting `deleteNode`, and then accessing it to set the pointer in its parent to NULL. You should change those lines to `deleteNode->parent->right = NULL; delete deleteNode;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a pointer to the parent. Here is a recursive version that should work: (pass by reference (`&`), in case you don't know, allows you to modify the variable, similar to pass by pointer; `BSTNode *&` is a pointer passed by reference, so we can modify the value of node->left/right (pointers) (not just what they're pointing to))

```
void BinarySearchTree::BSTDelete(int x, BSTNode *&node)
{
   if (node == NULL)
      return;
   if (x == node->sortKey)
   {
      if (isLeaf(node))
      {
         delete node;
         node = NULL;
      }
      else
      {
         // other stuff goes here
      }
      return;
   }
   else if (x < node->sortKey)
      BSTDelete(x, node->left);
   else
      BSTDelete(x, node->right);
}
```